# How can I strip the file extension from a list full of filenames?

Tags: python, list, path, file-extension

I am using the following to get a list with all the files inside a directory called `tokens`:

```
import os    
accounts = next(os.walk("tokens/"))[2]
```

Output:

```
>>> print accounts
['.DS_Store', 'AmieZiel.py', 'BrookeGianunzio.py', 'FayPinkert.py', 'JoieTrevett.py', 'KaroleColinger.py', 'KatheleenCaban.py', 'LashondaRodger.py', 'LelaSchoenrock.py', 'LizetteWashko.py',  'NickoleHarteau.py']
```

I want to remove the extension `.py` from each item in this list. I managed to do it individually using `os.path.splitext`:

```
>>> strip = os.path.splitext(accounts[1])
>>> print strip
('AmieZiel', '.py')
>>> print strip[0]
AmieZiel
```

I'm sure I'm overdoing things, but I can't figure out a way to strip the file extension from all the items in the list with a for-loop.

What would be the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can actually do this in one line with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in accounts]
```

But if you want/need a for-loop, the equivalent code would be:

```
lst = []
for x in accounts:
    lst.append(os.path.splitext(x)[0])
```

Notice too that I kept the `os.path.splitext(x)[0]` part.  This is the safest way in Python to remove the extension from a filename.  There is no function in the `os.path` module dedicated to this task and handcrafting a solution with `str.split` or something would be error prone.